# compute the integral/arcsin distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Let $\mathbb{P} (G_x \in dy, D_x \in dz) = dy dz \frac1{2\pi \sqrt{y(z-y)^3}}, \quad y< x<z$. Show that, for $y < x < z$ again,
$$\mathbb P(G_x < y, D_x > z) = \frac2 \pi \text{arcsin} \sqrt\frac{y}{z}.$$
I guess it has something to do with using $\int du \frac1{\sqrt{a^2 -u^2}} = \text{arcsin}\frac{u}{a} + C$, but I can't see how to manipulate the above equation so that I can use this result. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will also assume $y>0$ to have a well defined radical. By definition,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb P(G_x < Y\ , \ D_x > Z) 
\\
&\qquad=
\mathbb P(G_x \in[0,Y]\ , \ D_x \in [Z,\infty)) 
\\
&\qquad=
\int_{y\in[0,Y]}
\int_{z\in[Z,\infty)}
\frac 1{2\pi}\cdot\frac{dy\; dz}{\sqrt{y(z-y)^3}}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 1{2\pi}
\int_0^Y
\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}
\int_Z^\infty
\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(z-y)^3}}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 1{2\pi}
\int_0^Y
\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}
\left[-\frac 2{\sqrt{z-y}}\right]_Z^\infty
=
\frac 1{\pi}
\int_0^Y
\frac{dy}{\sqrt {y(Z-y)}}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{Substitution: $y=Z \sin^2 t$, with $y\in[0,Y]$, $t\in[0,a]$, where $a=\arcsin\sqrt{Y/Z}$,}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{and then $dy=Z\; d(\sin^2t)=2Z\; \sin t\cos t\; dt$, so}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac 1{\pi}
\int_0^a
\frac{2Z\;\sin t\cos t\; dt}{\sqrt {Z\sin^2 t\;Z(1-\sin^2 t)}}
=
\frac 1{\pi}
\int_0^a
2\;dt
=\frac 2\pi\cdot a
\\
&\qquad = \frac2 \pi \arcsin \sqrt\frac YZ\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$